# htmlunit java change input text

Tags: java, htmlunit

I use htmlunit.
How i can set value of text input if it does not have an attribute 'value' ?

```
<input type="text" onkeypress="test();" id="id" name="name" class="ttt">
```

I tried this, but nothing

```
    ((HtmlTextInput) portfolios.getHtmlElementById("id")).setText("text");
    ((HtmlInput) portfolios.getHtmlElementById("id")).setTextContent("text");
    ((HtmlInput) portfolios.getHtmlElementById("id")).setAttribute("value", "text");
```

Please help!

Comment: What does "but nothing" mean?

Comment: You should be able to set 'value' attribute even if you have not specifically added value to html text input.  What is the error you are facing?

Answer (score 12):

```
HtmlInput intputBox = (HtmlInput)portfolios.getHtmlElementById('id');

intputBox.setValueAttribute("text");
```

Answer (score -1):

Does [HtmlInput.setValueAttribute()](http://htmlunit.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/gargoylesoftware/htmlunit/html/HtmlInput.html#setValueAttribute-java.lang.String-) help?